# JavaScript: Regular Expression to find if string ends with specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the regular expression to find out if a string ends with the pattern:

_XX_XXX where X is a upper-case letter (A-Z)

Comment: is each `X` supposed to represent the _same_ letter, e.g. `_AA_AAA` through `_ZZ_ZZZ` ?

Comment: no, it can be any letter from A to Z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so?

```
/_[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{3}$/
```

`$` matches "end of input" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dollar))

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to check for same characters like WW_WWW or ZZ_ZZZ :

```
(.)\1{1}_\1{3}$/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/tE5zZ5